# Exercise about product and coproduct in a family

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am now studying the concept of product and coproduct in a category and I have found this exercise which I don't know how to solve. Could someone help me? please

Let us consider in the category $Ab$ a family of homomorphisms: $\{f_i:X_i\rightarrow{Y_i}\;i\in{I}\}$.

a)If $f_i$ is monomorphism for every $i\in{I}$, prove that $\prod_{i}X_i/\prod_{i}Y_i$ is isomorphic to  $\prod_{i}\left(X_i/Y_i\right)$

b)What can we say about $Ker(\oplus_{i}f_i)$?

**My attempt**

a)I am trying to prove that the natural map, $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_i,\dots)+\prod_{i}{Y_i} \mapsto{(x_1+Y_1,x_2+Y_2,\dots,x_i+Y_i,\dots)}$ is an isomorphis. But I think it has not sense  $\prod_{i}X_i/\prod_{i}Y_i$ because we don't know if  $\prod_{i}Y_i$ is a subgroup of $\prod_{i}X_i$.

b)I think that $Ker(\oplus_{i}f_i)=\oplus_{i}Ker(f_i)$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't we know that $\prod_i Y_i$ is a subgroup of $\prod_i X_i $ ? For both of these exercises you can either do them by hand or use universal properties and see what happens

Comment: @Max I am very lost. Could you give me a hint for a)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{f_{i}:X_{i}\rightarrow Y_{i}, i \in I\}$.

a) Let $f_{i}$ be a monomorphism for all $i \in I$. In $Ab$, monomorphisms are injective functions, so we can realize each $Y_{i}$ as a (normal!) subgroup of $X_{i}$, thus forming $X_{i}/Y_{i}$

Now, we need to use the universal property of the product to show that $\prod_{i}X_{i}/\prod_{i}Y_{i}$ and $\prod_{i}(X_{i}/Y_{i})$ are both products of $X_{i}/Y_{i}$. Doing so shows that they are isomorphic.

ie.: For maps $\pi_{i}:*\rightarrow X_{i}/Y_{i}$ and $g_{i}:X_{i}/Y_{i}\rightarrow G$, show that there is a unique map $\Theta:G\rightarrow *$ such that $\pi_{i}\circ\Theta = g_{i}$, where * is each of the products of $X_{i}/Y_{i}$ that we’re considering, and $G$ is an arbitrary abelian group.

For part b), $\oplus_{i} f_{i}:\prod_{i}X_{i}\rightarrow \prod_{i} Y_{i}$, where each $x_{i}\in X_{i}$ is $i$th element of the product and is mapped to $f_{i}(x_{i})$ as the $i$th element of the product.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: In a) I know how to prove the property that you mention. But how does that imply that $\prod_{i}X_i/\prod_{i}Y_i$ is isomorphic to $\prod_{i}(X_i/Y_i)$?

Comment: Any two products of the same underlying objects are isomorphic.